# How do i run a teardown project in playwright even if there are failures in the e2e_tests project

Tags: installation, dependencies, playwright, teardown

I have managed to run setup before all the tests and teardown after all the tests . i need to run teardown no matter whether e2e_tests are successful or not as currently it only runs if all e2e_tests are passed . what changes i should do in below projects.

```
projects: [
        {
            name: 'setup',
            testMatch: /global\.setup\.ts/,
          },
        {
            name: 'e2e_tests',
            use: {
                ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
            },
            dependencies: ['setup'],
        },
        {
            name: 'teardown',
            testMatch: /global\.teardown\.ts/,
            dependencies: ['e2e_tests'],
          },
    ],
```

thought of changing dependencies but dependencies order is correct it is just that the teardwon should not be dependent on whether e2e_tests are successful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the [teardown](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#teardown) property on the setup projects solves it. Here, teardown will always run - even if tests in e2e_tests project fails:

```js
  projects: [
    {
      name: "setup",
      testMatch: /global\.setup\.ts/,
      teardown: "teardown",  // <---- added
    },
    {
      name: "e2e_tests",
      use: {
        ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
      },
      dependencies: ["setup"],
    },
    {
      name: "teardown",
      testMatch: /global\.teardown\.ts/,
      // removed dependency to setup project
    },
  ],
```